# Can I get Scala to infer the Option type here?

Tags: scala, coding-style, type-inference

I want to call a generic function `f[X](...)`, and in my case `X` happens to be `Option[Y]`. I try to pass both `Some[...]` and `None` where the function expects `X`, but Scala insists that `X` be of type `Some[Y]`.

```
  def flattenOptionMap[A, B](input : Map[A, Option[B]]) : Option[Map[A, B]] = {
    input.foldLeft[Option[Map[A,B]]] (Some(Map.empty)) {
      case (_, (_, None)) => None
      case (None, (_, _)) => None
      case (Some(acc), (key, Some(value))) => Some(acc + (key -> value))
    }
  }
```

In this example, I had to explicitly specify that `Option[Map[A,B]]` should be used as generic type for `foldLeft`. All the necessary type information is already contained in the context, and typing cumbersome types like `Option[Map[A,B]]` more often than necessary in my opinion drastically reduces readability of my code.

Is there some way to get Scala to infer the type after all, or otherwise avoid copy-pasting the whole type?

Comment: You can omit the type if you use `Option(Map.empty[A, B])` as the start accumulator of the `foldLeft`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `Option(Map.empty[A, B])` as the start value of your `foldLeft`, Scala will infer the correct type as I wrote in the comments (and beefyhalo in his answer).

I would like to add, that if you are open to using Scalaz, you can just use the `sequence` function.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._ 

val mapSome = Map(1 -> Some("a"), 2 -> Some("b"))
val mapNone = Map(1 -> Some("a"), 2 -> Some("b"), 3 -> None)

mapSome.sequence
flattenOptionMap(mapSome)
// Option[Map[Int,String]] = Some(Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b))

mapNone.sequence
flattenOptionMap(mapNone)
// Option[Map[Int,String]] = None
```

Comment: I'd like to comment that this technique is useful in general for flipping instances of `F[G[_]]` to `G[F[_]]`. There are some rules of course, but `sequence` will effectively turn your object inside out! Something that comes up surprisingly often.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to improve readability, and to get help from the compiler to infer types, try:

```
def flattenOptionMap[A, B](input: Map[A, Option[B]]) =
  input.foldLeft(Option(Map.empty[A, B])) {
    case (_, (_, None))                  => None
    case (None, (_, _))                  => None
    case (Some(acc), (key, Some(value))) => Some(acc + (key -> value))
  }
```

or even better:

```
def flattenOptionMap[A, B](input: Map[A, Option[B]]) =
  input.foldLeft(Option(Map.empty[A, B])) {
    case (Some(acc), (key, Some(value))) => Some(acc + (key -> value))
    case _                               => None
  }
```

Or **even** better (in my opinion): Peter Neyens's answer. Use `sequence` from your `Traverse` instance.

Comment: Thank you (and Peter Neyens), that's exactly what I was looking for (and yes the sequence solution seems even better). I wouldn't know how to find the `apply` function by myself. It doesn't seem to show up in the [API ref](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Option), even though it's there in the source code and it even has a doc string.

Comment: What `Option.apply` is doing is really just constructing a `Some(..)` behind the scenes. i.e. It is just a factory method which creates either a `Some(..)` or a `None`. The key thing to notice is that the return type is the supertype `Option`, and not `Some`. In your original fold, the compiler infers that your accumulator is of type `Some`. When the fold returns `None`, scalac complains that `None`  clashes with the type `Some` (the type of the accumulator). This is why you had to provide type parameters to widen the type of `Some` to `Option`